# How to compile with GnuCOBOL

Tags: visual-studio-code, gnucobol

I am trying to add a task to compile a program but am having difficulty with setting environment variables. I have this:

```
{
  // See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink LinkId=733558
  // for the documentation about the tasks.json format
  "version": "2.0.0",
   "label": "GnuCOBOL - Compile (single file)",
   "type": "shell",
   "options": {
    "env": {
        "PATH=c:\\gnucobol3\\bin"
        "COB_CONFIG_DIR=c:\\gnucobol3\\config"
        "COB_COPY_DIR=c:\\gnucobol3\\copy"
        "COB_INCLUDE_PATH=c:\\gnucobol3\\include"
        "COB_LIB_PATH=c:\\gnucobol3\\lib"
       },
    "command": "cobc",
    "args": [
      "-x",
      "-std=mf",
      "-tPROG.LST",
      "BBCB.CBL"
      ]
    },
}
```

The env entries all have squiggly lines underneath and show errors "Colon expected".

I'd appreciate some help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The env entries all have squiggly lines underneath and show errors "Colon expected".

Because it expects a contained list which should have colons in and uses commas for separation (identical to the `options` variable) [note: that actually is a json issue, using that tag may be reasonable].
See [Schema for tasks.json](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks-appendix).

Also your script has some file names hard-wired (which is a vscode specific), you'll likely want to use the [supported variables](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/variables-reference) instead.

Untested result:

```
{
  // See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink LinkId=733558
  // for the documentation about the tasks.json format
  "version": "2.0.0",
   "label": "GnuCOBOL - Compile (single file)",
   "type": "shell",
   "options": {
    "env": {
        "PATH": "c:\\gnucobol3\\bin",
        "COB_CONFIG_DIR": "c:\\gnucobol3\\config",
        "COB_COPY_DIR": "c:\\gnucobol3\\copy",
        "COB_INCLUDE_PATH": "c:\\gnucobol3\\include",
        "COB_LIB_PATH": "c:\\gnucobol3\\lib",
       },
    "command": "cobc",
    "args": [
      "-x",
      "-std=mf",
      "-t${fileBasenameNoExtension}.LST",
      "${file}"
      ]
    },
}
```

Comment: Simon: thanks. I was going to try and 'generalise' the task when I had sorted out the errors. See post above.

Answer (score 1):

The file paths are for a Windows-based OS (`c:\ ...`). If you're using Linux, these are incorrect.

This format is JSON.

`"env": { ... }` takes key:value pairs (determined by the braces) so you will want:

```
"PATH": "c:\\gnucobol3\\bin",
```

A colon (`:`) separates the key and the value and a comma (`,`) separates  key:value pairs.

Unsure whether you need to escape the file paths `\\` or just `\`.

**NB** `"args": [ ... ]` takes an array of string values (determined by the square brackets) which is why it differs from `"env"`

Comment: Daz: thanks. I am not familiar with .JSON hence my puny attempts to define a task. I've modified tasks.json as you suggested and there no more squiggly lines :-)

Comment: No worries! It was new to all of us at some point. It's a widely-used format so you'll likely encounter it again. Good to "no squiggly lines" but -- as importantly -- does your code now compile?

Comment: Daz: yes, but I needed further assistance with respect to the structure of tasks.json. Thanks again.